# Unable to create converter for my class in Android Retrofit2 converter-simplexml library

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-framework

Im using Retrofit2 converter-simplexml library,the code run successful when I using converter-gson,but when I add simplexmlConverter,I got a exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.rengwuxian.rxjavasamples.model.ZhuangbiImage>
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate ResponseBody converter for java.util.List<com.rengwuxian.rxjavasamples.model.ZhuangbiImage>.
```

This is where I am trying to execute the retro http request:

```
private void search(String key) {
    subscription = getZhuangbiApi()
            .search(key)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}

public static ZhuangbiApi getZhuangbiApi() {
    if (zhuangbiApi == null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(simpleXmlConverterFactory)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJavaCallAdapterFactory)
                .build();
        zhuangbiApi = retrofit.create(ZhuangbiApi.class);

    }
    return zhuangbiApi;
}
```

My interface which turned to be my API

```
public interface ZhuangbiApi {

@GET("merchant/list")
Observable<List<ZhuangbiImage>> search(@Query("app_code") String appCode);
}
```

And the ZhuangbiImage class

```
@Root(name = "item")
public class ZhuangbiImage {

@Element(name = "title")
public String title;

@Element(name = "merchant_id")
public String merchantId;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, by saying "code runs fine when using gson"? Do you get successful response when using gson converter and unsuccessful, when using simple xml converter?

Comment: recheck your dependencies. Have you added this line `dependencies {  
    // Retrofit XML converter (Simple)
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.1.0'
}'

Comment: could you share your gradle file ? and sample response you are getting from web service

Comment: Are you testing  with call<List<ZhuangbiImage>> instead of Observable<List<ZhuangbiImage>>

Comment: try with this in your Api .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())

Comment: can you share some of your xml response?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: please share your xml response.

Answer (score 1):

XML can only be deserialized to a concrete type and not a list of types like JSON. In this case, the body type should represent the `<rss>` tag and its children and not `List<ZhuangbiImage>`.

More details from official retrofit team [Retrofit, XML and SimpleXmlConverterFactory problem](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2483)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your dependencies in gradle-file. Also check that the version of retrofit and converter is the same.

Comment: The version of retrofit does not need to match the version of the converter.